# Check if HTML table contains value or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table

```
      <table id="orderTable">

            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
```

And it is being filled in a loop when the page loads like this

```
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $price ?></td>
            </tr>
```

I am trying to allow a user to add items to the table by clicking an add button next to the relevant item in a menu before this table using the following jquery:

```
$(".menu-body").on('click', '#add', function() {
   add_to_table($(this));
});
```

I do not want the user to be able to add items to the table that are already in the table.

```
    function add_to_table(selector)
    {

        var itemName = $(selector).closest(".item").find(".item-name").html();
        var itemCost = $(selector).closest(".item").find(".item-price").html();
        content =  "<tr> <td>"+itemName+"</td> <td>"+itemCost+"</td> 

        var table = $("#orderTable"); 
        if(!$('#orderTable tr > td:contains("'+itemName+'")').length)
        {
            // If table does not contain this itemName already.
            table.append(content);
        }
        else {
            //table has item  
        }
    }
```

Currently, clicking the add button adds an item regardless of whether it is in the table or not, but then it correctly prevents a user from adding another one. So it works for items the user has added but it seems my conditional statement doesn't work for items that have already been put in the table by the PHP loop.

My desired behaviour is for the code to completely prevent a user from adding an item that is already in the table, but currently it only prevents them from adding items they have added themselves.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem. None of the classes in the js exist in the html

Comment: You can make the code in your question executable by inserting a "code snippet" (click the `<>` button in the edit toolbar) into your question.

Comment: `$(".menu-body").on('click', '#add', ...)` looks wrong as ids should be unique. `$("#menu-body").on('click', '.add', ...)` would be more convincing.

Comment: Sounds like the HTML served in the page differs from the HTML that is inserted dynamically.